# What is a straightforward way to send a signal to another app via IFTTT?

Tags: if-this-then-that

I've been doing some experimentation with [If This Then That](http://ifttt.com) service.

This service is a web application that allows you to concoct "recipes" between different "channels," e.g., send all my Tweets from Twitter to Facebook (or Google Reader, Evernote, etc.).

Currently, there is a limited number of channels.  I'd like to be able to send an alert to another custom application (even a desktop client, perhaps), but such a channel doesn't exist.

Aside from using an existing channel like email or Twitter, and triggering a special email or Tweet as output from IFTTT, with which the custom application could read the result by parsing the email or using the Twitter API, is there a more optimal way to make my own channel to control my custom application directly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about creating a pipe on [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/)? It will allow fine tuning input, output and options. Think of it as your own web service in the cloud, created through simple UI tools.

Comment: I've never used Pipes, I took a look at it, and the concept sounds interesting, but what are Yahoo's long term plans for it?

Comment: What are Yahoo's long term plans - that's the 6 billion dollar question in the valley right now :)

Comment: Hehe, you know what I mean.  I have in the back of my head that they were planning on phasing it out, but perhaps I am thinking of something else.

Comment: You may be thinking of BOSS. MS bought that gig from Yahoo and may be phasing it out in favor of BING

Comment: Pipes is shutting down in September 2015.

Comment: @glenviewjeff indeed it is. Didn't know that back in 2011 though :)

Answer (score 1):

IFTTT has created what they call "DO" buttons for Android and iOS. You can cause virtually any action to kick off by pressing a button on your screen or (soon) your watch.

[DO Button](https://ifttt.com/products/do/button)

(Nothing for your desktop, though.)